# Can I use a submodule to push common code to several branches in the containing repo?

Tags: git-submodules

I have a repo that contains several branches, and always will. I want to be able to push common code to all of the branches simultaneously. Is it feasible to use a submodule in my repo?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is. If you are asking how to add a submodule, please provide the steps you have already tried and what went wrong

Comment: I have not yet tried. I will be doing that today. Thank you for your assistance!